# Need to turn query into lat and lon using Bing API, works for some, but not all

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, bing-maps, bing-api

General geocoding is not problem.  I can put in a city or stae or what ever specific location and usually geocode correctly using Bing.  What I cant do is geocode things like intersections or fuzzy locations.  My example is "I25 and Colorado blvd".  In the Bing Maps site, this has no problem finding exactly what I am looking for.  When I use geocode or the bing maps search nothing is found.  Anyone have any clues how I can do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by adding the state and country name in the query.

Also, I assume you're using [VEMap.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429645.aspx), so you may want to try calling the [Locations API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) directly (especially as **Find** is no longuer available in the [most recent version of the Ajax API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427611.aspx)):

It might give a more explicit error message to help understand why it doesn't return a position.

Comment: I would have been more specific in my question but I was using the SOAP API not the REST one and it was GeoCoding not Search.  In the end the solution was actually to set the location for the searching user to a location near the intersection.